# jQuery - Check If any select option is selected or all selects options unselected

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

How to check if any select option is selected add class to parent div or all selects options unselected remove class from parent div?

html:

```
<div class="toggler_container">
<select name="select" id="aaa">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
</select>
<select name="select" id="bbb">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
</select>
<select name="select" id="ccc">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
</select>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".toggler_container select").on("change", function() {
if ($(this).val() == "0"){
    $(this).closest(".toggler_container").removeClass("booked");
}
else {
    $(this).closest(".toggler_container").addClass("booked");
}
});
```

Now works for selecting options, but not working for unselecting all options. I want to remove class from parent div only when all selects options unselected.
http://jsfiddle.net/nasxLpaL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check to see if the total number of selected options with the value of "0" equals the total number of `select` tags:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nasxLpaL/4/)

```
$(".toggler_container select").on("change", function () {
    var selected = $('option[value="0"]:selected');
    var selectTotal = $('select').length;

    if (selected.length == selectTotal) {
        $(this).closest(".toggler_container").removeClass("booked");
    } else {
        $(this).closest(".toggler_container").addClass("booked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to check all `selects` again if any of them is having some valid value and switch a `bit on/off`. Then based on bit value you can add/remove `class` to your `parent div`.

```
<div class="toggler_container">
<select name="select" id="aaa">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
</select>
<select name="select" id="bbb">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
</select>
<select name="select" id="ccc">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
    $(".toggler_container select").on("change", function() {
        var is_ok = false;
        $(".toggler_container select").each(function(key,obj){
            if($(obj).val() != 0)
                is_ok = true;
        });

        if(is_ok)
            $(this).closest(".toggler_container").addClass("booked");
        else
            $(this).closest(".toggler_container").removeClass("booked");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly what you are trying to do, I think you are trying to validate if the parent is selected. If this is true, yo have to implement some logic to validate. Like this:

```
if($('#select2 :selected').val() != 0 && $('#select1 :selected').val() == 0)
{
    //here you have to introduce your actions because the first select (select1) don't have any option selected.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$(".toggler_container select").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "0"){
        removeClass = true;
        $(this).parent().find("> select").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != 0)
                removeClass = false;
        })
        if(removeClass)
            $(this).closest(".toggler_container").removeClass("booked");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest(".toggler_container").addClass("booked");
    }
}
```